# SQL Join with SUM()

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two Tables

1. Product Details(About Product)
2. Sale Order Details(What Price is sold, quantity of products sold per order).

I am trying to do Join on Table 1 and Table 2 which should give the all the product details and   `sum(Quantity)`, `Sum(Price)`

Problem Facing: There are some products in Table 1 which are never sold, and those rows are missing in the result set, but I want details for all the rows in Table 1 with rows of  Products never purchased should be `NULL` or 'o'

Query I am Using:

```
select 
  P.*,
  ISNULL((sum([Q.Quantity])),0),
  ISNULL((sum([Q.Price])),0)
From Table1 P 
Left Outer Join Table2 Q on P.Product_ID = Q.Product_ID
```

Please help me with any suggestions that would work for me

Comment: you have to use the 'group by' clause in your query to get the sum

Comment: What's the matter? Exception? Misvalues? Not desired results? What do you expect and what's your result with that query (there's a missing group by clause maybe...)?

Comment: i didn't mentioned Previously but iam using group by clause also for all the columns in the Table 1,

Comment: The Problem iam facing is the result set is not having some Rows from Table 1, if there is no entry for that product in Table 2

Comment: Where is the `GROUP BY` clause? If you have one, the query seems correct, except for the `[Q.Quantity]`. I guess this should be `Q.[Quantity]`

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
select 
  P.Product_ID,
  ISNULL(sum([Q.Quantity]),0),
  ISNULL(sum([Q.Price]),0)
From Table1 P 
Left Outer Join Table2 Q 
on P.Product_ID = Q.Product_ID
group by
  P.Product_Id
```